# Sand road - blender render

Tags: particles, weight-painting

I want to do a sand road for my composition, I tried to do with the particle system with a group of objects and with some combinations of settings but the result is not looking what I want, as you see in the pictures sometimes just appear one stone in the vertex and sometimes are looking some areas without them, I tried with children, increasing the density (with the emission and the children), weight paint, .... The final result what I want is a not-so-straight road since the border to the door. Thanks.

[image: Verts]
[image: Faces]
[image: children]
[image: Weight]

Comment: Unless you're going to animate the sand, I would have thought the best way is to apply a material and texture to the faces you want. This might mean remodelling the topology, but would get the effect you're after?

Comment: Ok, the comment gave me an idea, however I keep the question open if someone needs it or if the answer was found with the particle system method.